# f(a) = inverse of a is an isomorphism iff a group G is Abelian

Tags: group-theory

> $G$ is a group and $f:G \rightarrow G$ is a function defined as $f(a)=a^{-1}$ where $a^{-1}$ is the inverse of $a$ under the group operation. Prove that $f$ is an isomorphism if and only if $G$ is abelian.

I understand that I have to prove $f(ab)=(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$. How might I do that?

Reference: Fraleigh p. 49 Question 4.40 in A First Course in Abstract Algebra

Answer (score 9):

First note that it is a bijection of $G$ onto $G$ no matter what. So this boils down to $G$ Abelian if and onbly if $f$ is a homorphism.

If $G$ is Abelian, I think you can show that $f$ is a homomorphism.

Now if $f$ is a homomorphism
$$
ab=(a^{-1})^{-1}(b^{-1})^{-1}=(b^{-1}a^{-1})^{-1}=(f(b)f(a))^{-1}=(f(ba))^{-1}=((ba)^{-1})^{-1}=ba.
$$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** No, we *always* have that $f(ab)=(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$. (One of the directions of) what you have to prove is that, if $G$ is abelian,
$$b^{-1}a^{-1}=(ab)^{-1}=\underset{\substack{\text{what it means for $f$}\\\text{to be a homomorphism}}}{\fbox{$f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$}}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$$

Comment: Are you assuming that $G$ is abelian and proving that $\varphi$ is a homomorphism, or vice versa?

Comment: I am not really doing neither. I am explaining that in order to prove the claim *"$G$ is abelian $\iff$ $f:G\to G$ defined by $f(a)=a^{-1}$ is a homomorphism"*, one of the directions that must be proven is *"$G$ is abelian $\implies$ $f:G\to G$ defined by $f(a)=a^{-1}$ is a homomorphism"*. Then I show that, if we expand the meaning of *"$f:G\to G$ defined by $f(a)=a^{-1}$ is a homomorphism"*, we find that it comes down to "$b^{-1}a^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$". I am leaving it to the reader on how to conclude this is true when $G$ is abelian :)

Answer (score 4):

HINT: You have to prove two things:

1. If $G$ is Abelian, then $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$ for all $a,b\in G$, which means that $(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$ for all $a,b\in G$.
2. If $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$ for all $a,b\in G$, i.e., if $(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$ for all $a,b\in G$, then $G$ is Abelian.

You need just one basic fact for both: that in **any** group $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$.

Answer (score -1):

$f\colon G → G$ defined by $f(x)=x^-1$
$f$ isomorphism $⇒$ f is a 1-1 homomorphism
$∀ x,y∈G, xy = ((xy)^{-1})^{-1} = ((y^{-1})(x^{-1}))^{-1}
 = (f(y)(x))^{-1} = f(yx)^{-1}$  (∵$f$ is a homomorphism)
$= ((yx)^{-1})^{-1}$ (by mapping defining)
$= yx (∵ (a^{-1})^{-1} = a) 
∴ xy = yx ⇒ G$ is abelian