# Prove that $G$ is abelian if and only if the mapping $f : G → G$ defined by $f(g) = g^{-1}$ is a group isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $G$ be a group. Prove that $G$ is abelian if and only if the mapping  $f : G → G$ defined by $f(g) = g^{-1}$, for all $g\in G$, is a group isomorphism.

Anyone who can help me solving this one?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Yea. But I don't know if my answer is correct. So Im asking if anyone can give me an answer. A correct one

Comment: Please edit your question to include your attempt and explain where you are stuck or why you have doubts about your answer.

Comment: I am sure this has been asked many times before on this site. Have you searched?

Comment: I looked most of them but none exactly answer this

Comment: What is missing from http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326589/fa-inverse-of-a-is-an-isomorphism-iff-a-group-g-is-abelian, for example?

Comment: f(ab) =f(a)f(b)...so( ab)-1=a-1.b-1

Answer (score 0):

$f(a) =a^{-1}$

$f(b)=b^{-1}$

$f(a)f(b)=a^{-1}\cdot b^{-1} = f(ab) = b^{-1}\cdot a^{-1}$

$ba=ab$ taking inverse on both sides..

Comment: Note that the Question asks about "if and only if".  I'll add some math formatting using [MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and $\LaTeX$.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: note $f$ in general is an anti-iso, that is $f(gh)=h^{-1}g^{-1} = f(h)f(g)$, so...

Comment: It is not anti-iso

Comment: @LCedCose, it **is** an anti-iso, for all groups. The point of the hint is that if it is *also* an iso, then you can surely do something...

Comment: @LCedCose Anti-iso means it is bijetcive and $f(gh)=f(h)f(g)$